# Helping out in a hostile situation - What am I?

Tags: riddle

This is my first puzzle, so I hope this is good enough for everyone...

Sometimes I am automatically forgotten but...

I always have a purpose.

I can help out in a hostile situation.

Firstly, I'll get you nowhere fast.

On the flip side, I can even take you backwards.

What am I?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My attempt at this puzzle is:

> Gear
>
>
> Updated after OP improvements - not limited to vehicle gears due to later clues

Sometimes I am automatically forgotten

> A vehicle may have automatic gears so the driver can forget which gear they are in.

I always have a purpose

> Gear is equipment that is used for a particular purpose.

I can help out in a hostile situation

> Riot gear in a hostile situation  (OP's help)
>
>  Original - Adverse weather conditions call for appropriate clothing (gear). Also can be weapons.

Firstly, I'll get you nowhere fast

> First gear in a car won’t get you anywhere fast

On the flip side, I can even take you backwards.

> In reverse gear you go backwards

Comment: ... just as good as my answer - +1

Comment: @Tom Correct! The hostile situation was specifically meant to infer riot gear just to include a hint unrelated to cars, it was meant to be 'gear' in general so not just specifically vehicle gears.

Comment: @hypern - that's super -  and it's an improvement on my answer - thanks for this better reasoning - good puzz!

Answer (score 7):

I think it is

> Backups

because

> **Sometimes I am automatically forgotten but...**
>  
>  Rotation of backups can automatically delete them after time
>  
>  **I always have a purpose.**
>  
>  Who takes backups for no purpose?
>  
>  **I can help out in a hostile situation.**
>  
>  After a hostile attack on a computer, often the best course is to restore from backup
>  
>  **Firstly, I'll get you nowhere fast.**
>  
>  Restoring backups is slow
>  
>  **On the flip side, I can even take you backwards.**
>  
>  'Time-machine' type restore, takes you back to an earlier position in time

Comment: I like this answer - especially suits helping out in a hostile situation very nicely along with the other clues!

Comment: @abligh This is a great answer, but its not the one I had in mind